# Symfony2 FormBuilder with Entity class

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I have a form that works well, there is just one issue with it and I'm hoping that I'll get an answer on how to do what I need to do.

```
<?php

namespace ADS\UserBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContext;

class UserType extends AbstractType {
private $type;
public function __construct($type) {
    $this->type = $type;
}

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
    $builder
        ->add('firstName', 'text', array('required' => true))
        ->add('lastName', 'text', array('required' => true));
    $builder->add('email', 'email', array('required' => true));
    $builder->add('parentCompany', 'entity', array(
        'class' => 'ADSUserBundle:Company',
        'expanded' => false,
        'empty_value' => 'CHOOSE ONE',
        'required' => false,
        'property' => 'companyName'
    ))
    ->add('enabled', 'choice', array('choices' => array('1' => 'Enabled', '0' => 'Disabled')))
    ->add('roles', 'entity', array(
            'class' => 'ADSUserBundle:Roles',
            'required' => true,
            'property' => 'displayName',
        ));
}

public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver) {
    $resolver->setDefaults(array('data_class' => 'ADS\UserBundle\Entity\User'));
}

public function getName() { return 'ads_userbundle_user'; }
}
```

I have this form, the portion I am looking at is the 'roles' portion...  Right now it created a multiple select box ( as I expect it to ), though the value is sequentially ie:  0,1,2,3,4...

What I really need is to figure out how to take this entity, and make the `property` to be the `displayName` ( as it is now ) and get the value to be the corresponding `internalName`  This way it'll give me an array like:

```
array('ROLE_EXAMPLE' => 'EXAMPLE', 'ROLE_EXAMPLE1' => 'EXAMPLE1')
```

Any ideas how to accomplish this is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kamil Adryjanek is correct, it is going to be much easier if you change it from an `entity` to a `choice` field.  I've done some testing, both with `FOSUserBundle` and without the bundle - in both cases I hit some interesting road blocks.

First, I tried to run it through `QueryBuilder` in a `repository`, that didn't work out as it should have.  The reason being, the fact that you wanted to be returning an `array` instead of a `ORM` object causes an error.

So next, I started looking at creating the choice field.  All the guides, say to use the fieldname `role` instead of `roles` so I tried that, but I then had to duplicate the `UserInterface` from `FOSUserBundle` - I didn't want to do that -- so here I am stressed, and trying to figure it out.

Here is what I ended up doing, which works well.

```
 private $normalRoles = array();
```

then in the `__construct` I add:  `$this->normalRoles = $roles;`

Here is the builder:

```
$builder
    ->add('roles', 'choice', array(
            'multiple' => true,
            'choices' => $this->normalRoles
        ))
;
```

Originally, I left the multiple part out, figuring that it'd at least let me see an option box.  I ended up getting an `Array to String` conversion error.  So, adding the `'multiple' => true` in, fixes that error.

Then, in my repository I created a function called `normalizeRoles`

```
 public function normalizeRoles() {
    $data = array();
    $qb = $this->getEntityManager();
    $query = $qb->createQuery(
        "SELECT r.internalName, r.displayName FROM AcmeUserBundle:Roles r"
    )->getArrayResult();
    foreach ($query as $k => $v) {
        $data[$v['internalName']] = $v['displayName'];
    }
    return $data;
}
```

From here, we just have to make some small edits in the `DefaultController` of the `UserBundle` in the `newAction` and `editAction` ( both are the same changes )

So, first off is to put into your Controller `use Acme/UserBundle/Entity/Roles` in order to avoid any errors and be able to get that repository.

Next, right before you create the form you run the `normalizeRoles()` function

`$roles = $em->getRepository('AcmeUserBundle:Roles')->normalizeRoles()`

Then, you pass it through the construct via: `new UserType($roles)`

full line for that would look like this:

```
$form = $this->createForm(new UserType($roles), $entity, array(
        'action' => $this->generateUrl('acmd.user.edit', array(
                'id' => $id)
            )
    ));
```

or for new:

```
$form = $this->createForm(new UserType($roles), $entity, array(
        'action' => $this->generateUrl('acmd.user.new')
            )
    ));
```

At this point --  You'll have a working system that will allow you to dynamically add roles into a database table, and then associate those with a new or current user.

Answer (score 1):

You can try do it via query_builder attribute:

```
$builder->add('roles', 'entity', array(
    'class' => 'ADSUserBundle:Roles',
    'required' => true,
    'property' => 'displayName',
    'query_builder' => function (RolesRepository $queryBuilder) {
        return $queryBuilder->someMethod() // some method in this repository that return correct query to db.
    },
));
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case it would be better to use `choice` field Type (http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html)  instead of entity and pass some role choices as option to form because entity field Type get entity id as key for choices:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {

  ...

  $builder->add('roles', 'choice', array(
    'choices'   => $options['role_choices']
  ));

  ... 
}

public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver) {
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
      'data_class'    => 'ADS\UserBundle\Entity\User',
      'role_choices'  => array()
    ));
}
```

Notice: it's recommended to pass variables to form through options parameter, not in constructor.

Answer (score 0):

if I understand your question correctly, you need a data transformers. They help you to show data in form as you want.

Documentation: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html